# Bootstrap 3 column not ordering properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid, multiple-columns

I am using Bootstrap 3 and trying to stack grids on top of each other (A, B, C, D, E)

The Mobile grid stacking seems to work fine but the main problem is when i view it on desktop the grids don't seem to fit in place as they should, for example the box for E:

[image: A visual description of my problem with the Mobile Grid]

This is my code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8">
    <!-- Main Hero Image -->
     <p>A</p>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-4">
    <!-- Side Content-->
    <p>B</p>
   </div>

     <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8">
        <!--Music Player-->
       <p>C</p>

       <!--Upcoming Events-->
       <p>D</p>     
     </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-8">
      <!--Recent Events-->
      <p>E</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

The size of the columns should be 8 for A & E and size 4 for B, C & D

Comment: Can you put your code on something like Bootply

Comment: Heres the link for Bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/FRltfaxrTw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/C5rpV/1/
for better understanding look at this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fibvt

just changed the

```
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4">
      <!--Recent Events-->
      <p>E</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: cannot believe i forgot to change that 8 to a 4! Thanks a lot!